# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([8])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1]))

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to modify the inceptionNet to make binary classification for my dataset, however I received the following error:

```
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

  | Name      | Type              | Params
------------------------------------------------
0 | model     | Inception3        | 25.1 M
1 | criterion | BCEWithLogitsLoss | 0     
2 | train_acc | Accuracy          | 0     
3 | val_acc   | Accuracy          | 0     
------------------------------------------------
25.1 M    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
25.1 M    Total params
100.455   Total estimated model params size (MB)
Sanity Checking:
0/? [00:00<?, ?it/s]
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/data_connector.py:245: PossibleUserWarning: The dataloader, val_dataloader 0, does not have many workers which may be a bottleneck. Consider increasing the value of the `num_workers` argument` (try 8 which is the number of cpus on this machine) in the `DataLoader` init to improve performance.
  category=PossibleUserWarning,
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-be2f07460d17> in <module>()
----> 1 trainer3.fit(model3, train_loader, val_loader)

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   3128 
   3129     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 3130         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   3131 
   3132     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([8])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1]))
```

the tensor([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],device ='cuda:0') is from printing the label (as I said it is a binary classification), here is the code:

```
import torchmetrics

class CheastCancer_ConvNet(pl.LightningModule):

  def __init__(self,init_weights=True):
    super().__init__()

    self.model = torchvision.models.inception_v3()
    self.model.Conv2d_1a_3x3 = BasicConv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
    # self.model.Mixed_5b.branch5x5_2 = BasicConv2d(48, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1, bias=True)
    
    self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 1e-3)

    #loss function
    self.criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight = torch.tensor([3]))

    #eval matrix
    self.train_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
    self.val_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()

    #list to store loss curve and accuracy curve
    self.traincc, self.valacc = [],[]
    self.trainloss, self.valloss = [],[0]

  def forward(self, data):
    pred = self.model(data)
    return pred

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    img, label = batch
    pred = self(img)
    # label = label.float()
    print(label)
    loss = self.criterion(pred[0],label.float())
    acc = self.train_acc(pred[0],label)

    self.log("Train Loss", loss)
    self.log("Step Train ACC", self.train_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred[0]), label.int()))

    return loss
  
  def training_epoch_end(self, outs):
    self.log("Train ACC", self.train_acc.compute())

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    img, label = batch
    # label = label.float()
    pred = self(img)
    print(label)
    # loss = self.loss_fn(pred,label)
    loss = self.criterion(pred[0],label.float())

    self.log("Train Loss", loss)
    self.log("Step Train ACC", self.val_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred[0]), label.int()))

    return loss
  
  def validation_epoch_end(self, outs):
    self.log("Val ACC", self.val_acc.compute())

  def configure_optimizers(self):
      return [self.optimizer]
```

Basically I changed the first layer of the convolution because my pictures are black and white, and changed the output to only 1. For some reasons the predicitons are not the same as the VGGnet and ResNet, but I don't know why the label also gives something weird.... why the label size is 8? Also, how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the BCE loss.
In particular, the line:

```
loss = self.criterion(pred[0],label.float())
```

Should be:

```
loss = self.criterion(pred,label.float())
```

The same needs to be applied to the following lines.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but the same error message changed to : Target size (torch.Size([8])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([8, 1]))

Comment: and if I change the label to : `label.float().unsqueeze(1)` , the error output will be `AttributeError: 'InceptionOutputs' object has no attribute 'size'`, it seems I can never run the code successfully ...

Comment: if i do target.size() , it will return `torch.Size([8, 1])`, but from the error output, it seems the criterion is still the source of error. I am getting very confused

Comment: Can you provide the shape for both, pred and label?

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the problem. The returned object is a nametuple